# How do I toggle which information is included in a sum?

Tags: vba, excel

I have about a hundred rows of data in a column. I'd like to put some sort of user interface device (`radio button`? `check box`?) next to each row. Then I want to only sum the rows that are selected.

I honestly don't know where to begin...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: First question - do you want to use filters? Or do you want all hundred rows to be seen regardless of which are selected?

Comment: Can't use filters, otherwise I would just use the subtotal function. All rows need to be visible. This is for quick "what-if" scenario calculations

Comment: You're going to ask your users to click or unclick 100 radio buttons / checkboxes? Doesn't sound like a user friendly GUI to me.

Comment: All boxes will be checked by default. The user can uncheck/recheck as they see fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to stay away from filters, the easiest way to do this is to construct a helper column that serves as an indicator (1 = Include in Sum, 0 = Exclude from Sum).

Once you have an indicator column set up, your sums can be easily done per column by using the SUMPRODUCT function. =SUMPRODUCT($indicator column, summed column)

For the user interface, if checkbox/radio button are your only options, things are a little more complicated, and I'll edit the answer.

The easiest/quickest way is to set up a column that uses Data Validation to set up a Yes/No dropdown.

[image: data validation for your Yes/No column]

Then set up your indicator column to be something like this: =IF(A1="Yes",1,0)
(Assuming A1 is your Yes/No column)

Now your users should be able to easily pick Yes/No on each row, which will automatically propagate to 0/1 and from there update the sums (really sumproducts) for the column.

To make things look nicer, you can then hide the indicator column - no need to show it to the user.

[image: finished product]

Comment: Can i put a default "No" in there to start?

Comment: Yes. Just set up one cell with the data validation, then type in "No". Just copy that cell down and they will all start out as No. Good luck!

Comment: I'm making good progress but now I'm stuck. I get a 1004 error when I reach the "rng3.value..." line of the code below:

Comment: You shouldn't need to be using any ranges.. unless I am missing something? There's no code involved in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this a simple formula will do. Let's say that the data you want to sum is in Column A and runs from A2:A100 and your control Column is B running from B2:B100. We'll also assume that the cell you want your result in is A101

Set the B column font to Marlett.

Enter and 'a' in any cell in Column B which you want to include in your sum. MUST BE LOWER CASE. You'll get a check mark.

Set the formula in A101 to =SUMIF(B1:B100,"a",A1:A100)

Comment: This is a great approach. I don't think it will work for my purposes because this workbook will eventually be distributed and I don't want to instruct people to type "a" instead of clicking a check box.

Comment: Wow, this is a cool trick! I dig this checkmark.. you could easily combine this with a data validation list and end up with a "check" or "blank" dropdown.